# Android connect to the database of azure with mobile service

Tags: azure

you can see the tables in a database Azure from a mobile Service azure? , the idea is accessed from android to tables in the database azure

Comment: Flagging this as unclear. Please see [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Azure mobile services works (in the .NET version) with a TableController.  This is a standard MVC controller, but it uses a base class to remove the need to do boilerplate code when you're only interested in doing simple CRUD on a client, and the server doesn't have large amounts of logic to do.

Basically you'll define your table through Entity Framework, either code or DB first, and then the controller can take it from there.